# Format double value in scientific notation

Tags: java, formatting, scientific-notation

I have a double number like `223.45654543434` and I need to show it like `0.223x10e+2`.

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: In proper scientific notation the number will be 2.23e-2, not 0.223e-3.

Comment: … and of course I mean 2.23e+2, not 2.23e-2. I claim that's because OP the `3` is easier to notice than the `-`.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

Finally I do it by hand:

```
public static String parseToCientificNotation(double value) {
        int cont = 0;
        java.text.DecimalFormat DECIMAL_FORMATER = new java.text.DecimalFormat("0.##");
        while (((int) value) != 0) {
            value /= 10;
            cont++;
        }
        return DECIMAL_FORMATER.format(value).replace(",", ".") + " x10^ -" + cont;
}
```

Comment: successive division!?  see answer below

Comment: Answers may be "below", "above", or just anywhere else depending on many factors, for example how you sort them (most active, oldest, most voted). If you need to refer to another answer, link to it (click 'share' to get a permalink to the answer)

Comment: Answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2944928/1215260 would be my preference rather than successive division.

Answer (score 39):

```
    System.out.println(String.format("%6.3e",223.45654543434));
```

results in

```
    2.235e+02
```

which is the closest I get.

more info : http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: Or `System.out.printf("%6.3e\n", 223.23525)`

Comment: Please explain what the "%6.3e" means. I can deduce that .3e means that there's only three digits after the . but what does the 6 mean?

Comment: @DonLarynx it means there are maximum 6 meaningful digits in the result. For more details check the link to the syntax for the formatter.

Answer (score 28):

This answer will save time for the 40k+ people who are googling "java scientific notation."

**What does Y mean in `%X.YE`?**

The number between the `.` and `E` is the number of **decimal places (NOT the significant figures).**

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.3E",223.45654543434));
// "2.235E+02"
// rounded to 3 decimal places, 4 total significant figures
```

The `String.format` method requires you to specify the number of decimal digits to round to. If you need to preserve the exact significance of the original number then you will need a different solution.

**What does X mean in `%X.YE`?**

The number between the `%` and `.` is the **minimum number of characters the string will take up.** (this number is not necessary, as shown above the the string will automatically fill if you leave it out)

```
System.out.println(String.format("%3.3E",223.45654543434));
// "2.235E+02" <---- 9 total characters
System.out.println(String.format("%9.3E",223.45654543434));
// "2.235E+02" <---- 9 total characters
System.out.println(String.format("%12.3E",223.45654543434));
// "   2.235E+02" <---- 12 total characters, 3 spaces
System.out.println(String.format("%12.8E",223.45654543434));
// "2.23456545E+02" <---- 14 total characters
System.out.println(String.format("%16.8E",223.45654543434));
// "  2.23456545E+02"  <---- 16 total characters, 2 spaces
```

Answer (score 23):

From [Display numbers in scientific notation](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.text/display-numbers-in-scientific-notation.html). (*Copy/pasting because the page seems to be having issues*)

---

You can display numbers in scientific notation using `java.text` package. Specifically `DecimalFormat` class in `java.text` package can be used for this aim.

The following example shows how to do this:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;

public class TestScientific {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
     new TestScientific().doit();
  }

  public void doit() {
     NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();

     int maxinteger = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
     System.out.println(maxinteger);    // 2147483647

     formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.######E0");
     System.out.println(formatter.format(maxinteger)); // 2,147484E9

     formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.#####E0");
     System.out.println(formatter.format(maxinteger)); // 2.14748E9


     int mininteger = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
     System.out.println(mininteger);    // -2147483648

     formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.######E0");
     System.out.println(formatter.format(mininteger)); // -2.147484E9

     formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.#####E0");
     System.out.println(formatter.format(mininteger)); // -2.14748E9

     double d = 0.12345;
     formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.#####E0");
     System.out.println(formatter.format(d)); // 1.2345E-1

     formatter = new DecimalFormat("000000E0");
     System.out.println(formatter.format(d)); // 12345E-6
  }
}
```

Comment: *"Copy/pasting because the page seems to be having issues"* Also because SO should stand on its own, in case external references move, go away, etc.

Comment: true enough, however i usually just c/p the really pertinent parts and then link to the original source for more detailed info.  In this case, the original source is not  working well, so I put it all in here.