# Float to big decimal

Tags: java

I have to write a program with the following requirements:

1. I have a variable of type float, say float a = 3333.333f;
2. I have a variable of type int, say int b = 9999;

When I perform a*b in calculator, the result will be 33329996.667

After rounding up the decimals to 2 places, I want to print the value as 33329996.67 in java. I tried with long, double, float, big decimal, But couldnt succeed.

Can anyone please help me solving this?

Comment: Did you make sure to cast appropriately? What exact code have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

`float` only has 7 digits of precision, so its not a good choice for a result with more than 7 digits. `double` has up to 16 digits of accuracy and is a better choice.

```
double a = 3333.333;
int b = 9999;
System.out.printf("%.2f", a * b);
```

prints

```
33329996.67
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine the number of digits after the comma you have to apply a little trick:

First shift the comma to the right for the amount of digits you want to have, then cut the whole number e.g. with Math.ceil(float f) and then shift the comma back to the left.

That will illustrate that:

```
float f = 33329996.667;

float f2 = Math.ceil((f * 100)) / 100;
```

f2 now has the value 33329996.67.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: For formatting have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944822/format-double-value-in-scientific-notation)

Comment: Thanks Marc for yur answer. But I have one doubt.
When I do Sysout for 33329996.66, it displays as 3.3329996E7. How to print as 33329996.66

Comment: This technique does not work in over 90% of cases. It can't. Floating-point values don't have decimal places to truncate, they have binary place. If you want decimal places you have to use a decimal radix.

Comment: I would use `round` instead of `ceil`

Comment: @PeterLawrey I would use a decimal radix via BigDecimal or DecimalFormat. At least it will do what is required. Nothing in Math will.

Comment: @PeterLawrey well you're right Math.round(double d) decides on its own whether to round up or down but I think i depends on the requirements :)

Comment: It doesn't depend on the requirements.  The problem is that `float` and `double` don't care about decimal places, they only care about binary places.  You _must_ use `BigDecimal` or `DecimalFormat` to deal with a number of decimal places.

Comment: BigDecimal is the best solution for the most predictable behaviour. Most financial houses and trading system however use `double` (dollars) or `int` or `long` (cents) What might be the best in theory is rarely needed in practice.