# TextView not displaying large values in scientific notation

Tags: java, android, xml, double, scientific-notation

Here is the text view:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/input"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000000"
android:gravity="right"
android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textSize="50sp"/>
```

I'm using :

```
String inputStr = doubleToString(result);
input.setText(inputStr);
```

The `TextView` simply expands by more lines to fit large numbers (now string). I guess that's because I have used `WRAP_CONTENT` as height but I can't use `FILL_PARENT`.

If I use `android:lines="1"` then I simply can't see all the numbers.
So how do I convert the double into scientific notation before displaying in the `TextView`?

### Edit

I just discovered that *it is being displayed in scientific notation but only for values greater than 10^12* But they're not just visible.

So i just it to display for values greater than 1E10.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format double value in scientific notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944822/format-double-value-in-scientific-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert double to scientific notation like that

```
public static String parseToCientificNotation(double result) {
    int cont = 0;
    java.text.DecimalFormat DECIMAL_FORMATER = new java.text.DecimalFormat("0.##");
    while (((int) result) != 0) {
        result/= 10;
        cont++;
    }
    return DECIMAL_FORMATER.format(result).replace(",", ".") + " x10^ -" + cont;
```

}

Comment: Wonderful. It was formatting even the smaller numbers. I modified it. Thank you.