# How to express numbers in scientific notation in java?

Tags: java, numbers, notation, scientific-notation

I'm writing a program that deals with planets' mass and diameter; These quantities are expressed in scientific notation. My question is NOT, mind you, NOT how does one print large numbers the right way (That's using printf(), duh), its how I would... "type" these numbers, I guess you could say. For example, the mass of mercury is expressed:

```
3.30 x 10ˆ23
```

And in my array of planet masses, an element would look:

```
33.0 * Math.pow(10, 23)
```

However, I don't quite think this is the right way - it looks like it would throw an exception... So how could I express large numbers like that from a programmer's perspective? Thanks!

Comment: I believe this thread answers the exact same question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944822/format-double-value-in-scientific-notation

Comment: I think this is not the same question ("NOT how does one print large numbers the right way"), the real question is how to represent scientific notation in source code.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[Section 3.10.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) talks about floating-point literals in Java.  In short, provide the decimal part as if it were scientific notation, but instead of `x 10^23` you would write `e23`:

```
3.30e23
```

To write one with a negative exponent, you can do that easily also for `6.67 x 10^(-11)`:

```
6.67e−11
```

Answer (score 14):

Java does support scientific notation:

```
3.30e23
```