# How to write a small number using java

Tags: java

How to write a very small number, which is approaching the limit 0?
Like this:

```
double eps = 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001;
```

This is a constant, but in the code it looks terrible. Is there a shorter form?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984040/how-to-express-numbers-in-scientific-notation-in-java

Answer (score 8):

Java supports [*scientific notation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) for expressing double literals. You can write a small number, say, 10<sup>-12</sup> like this:

```
double eps = 1E-12;
```

Comment: It would be worth adding that Java has a minimum number it can store in ``.