# What are those numbers and what is their type?

Tags: java, double, literals, primitive-types

Ok I got a couple values here:

```
'F', 0xf, 070, 70L, 77e-1f, 7.7f, 7.77e1, 77.7
```

I know that `'F'` is a `char` and that `70L` has the type `long`. Also, I know that `0xf` is hex(right?) and that `070` is octal. But what are those other numbers? And why the hell is `77.7` `double` and not `float` as well?

Comment: *Why the hell* you have included things that you already know? :)

Comment: *"And why the hell is 77.7 double and not float as well?"* Research isn't your strength, right? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2. At least you got a "pity upvote" by another bad user :).

Comment: I don't get it. So 77.7 isn't the same as 77,7?

Comment: why the link to the JLS? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html explains it as well, and there is even a chance that people new to Java will also understand it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

- About `77.7`:

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter F
>   or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally end with the
>   letter D or d.

- `0xf` is not of type `hex`. There is no type `hex`. It's simply an `int` wirtten in hex. Just like `070` is an `int` written in octal.
- The literal `77e-1f`is clearly a float since it ends with `f`.
- The `e` is `exponent` i.e. `77e-1f` is in fact `77 * 10^(-1)` or `7.7`. The literal `7.77e1` is a double for the same reason `77.7` is a double, it's just that `7.77e1` is equal to `7.77 * 10 ^ 1` = `77.7`.

Answer (score 0):

The only two which you didn't explain yourself:

```
7.7f
```

That f means **float** - it indicates that this should not be a **double** literal, but well, a float one! You see, by default any "floating point" literals are automatically of type **double**, you need the "f" in order to enforce the "smaller" float type.

And

```
77e-1f
```

is using scientific notation, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984040/how-to-express-numbers-in-scientific-notation-in-java) for example for further explanations.

Answer (score 0):

> And why the hell is 77.7 double and not float as well?

**Float** numbers has to be denoted with `f` on the end but **double** numbers don't require `d` on the end.

`77e-1f` is a **float** number `77` to the power of `10^-1`, so it equals `7.7`.

The same with `7.77e1` == `77.7`

Comment: But we are talking about java. And in Java, the literal 070 is octal. Always.

Comment: Thanks, I removed that part.

Comment: 7.77e1 = 7 x 10 to-the-power 1 = 77.7, not 0.777

Comment: you changed it to 7.77 which is still wrong... 7.77e1 = 77.7.

Comment: What a mistake, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In Java numerical literals that contain a dot are of type double by default. If you want a float, you neef to append the `f`.

The numbers containing the `e` are in exponential or scientific notation, but I am not going to explain it here because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

> **77e-1** means this: `77` is number-multiplier, `e` (or `E`) means `base 10`, and `-1` means exponent.

So the result is `77` by (`10` powered by `-1`), or `77` by `.1`, i. e. **`7.7`**

The name of this notation is **scientific** or **logarithmic** and is good for very large or very small numbers, e. g. `1 million = 1.000.000` may be expressed as `1e6`