# Java - Format numbers in scientific notation

Tags: java, double

I want to format this `String`:

`String number = "3.4213946120686956E-9";`

to this:

`String number = "3.42E-9";`

Rounding to 2 decimals. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944822/format-double-value-in-scientific-notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `new DecimalFormat("0.##E0")`. Javadoc: [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Example:

```
public class Test {

  private static java.text.DecimalFormat sf = new java.text.DecimalFormat("0.##E0");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sf.format(Double.parseDouble("3.4213946120686956E-9")));
  }
};
```

Output: 3.42E-9

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most elegant solution but you could:

EX: String number = "3.4213946120686956E-9";

**if** the String has a period and an E in it

split the string by the period, and get the first 2 characters after the period = 42

get the last 3 characters at the end = E-9

and then just add it back together with all the characters before the period = 3 + "." + 42 + E-9

Comment: Nice, but that method does not round up :)

Answer (score 1):

Read about [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

```
    String number = "3.4213946120686956E-9";
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.##E0");
    System.out.println(format.format(new BigDecimal(number)));
```