# How to store numbers using scientific notation?

Tags: java

The title says it all: is there a way to store a really huge number using scientific notation?
Something like `BigInteger i = 1.9891*10^30`?

For the record, I'm trying to store the mass of the Sun. In fact, in the end, I would like to be able to store the masses of several stars and planets, not to mention their radiuses, surface areas, volumes, etc. And I figure that storing the full values would use way to much memory.

Or do I need to craft my own class to handle scientific calculations and store such values?

EDIT

What I mean is, if I store the number 1.9891e30, how much disk space will be used? As much as if I stored 1989100000000000000000000000000, or less?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944822/format-double-value-in-scientific-notation

Comment: @CodeNewbie I don't think it is a duplicate. I'm not only asking how to display a number in scientific, I'm asking if there is a way to store it, so as to take less disk space than the fully written value. I'll update the OP to add some clarification.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good Javascript BigDecimal library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744099/is-there-a-good-javascript-bigdecimal-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `E` instead of *10^30 so:

`BigInteger i = 1.9891E30?`

I'm not sure if you won't have to use `double` for it though

To display it in scientific notation use `printf()` method and `%g` flag to display in scientific notation so something like:

```
System.out.printf("%g", i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to know if storing a value in scientific notation will help you save memory, I would like to point you to [the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

> The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point.

So when you store the number 1989100000000000000000000000000, you will still utilize 8 bytes of data. You can represent it as 1.9891E30 (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944822/format-double-value-in-scientific-notation) for code help) or as 1989100000000000000000000000000, but that will not change the storage size in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `double`? You can store values up to around `10^4931`.

For displaying value, you can use `format` (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)) or `NumberFormat` (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)).