# String.format("%.5e",someDouble) results in a number with 13 decimal places & no "e+xx"

Tags: java, string, format, exponential

As the question suggests, I'm using `String.format("%.5e",someDouble)` because I want the following format `#.#####E+#`.

I'm making a calculator for a tutorial. Let's say I'm typing in 333,333,333,333 * 333,333,333,333. The answer in the correct format should be "`1.11111E+23`". But instead it's giving me "`1.1111111111089`" no matter what number I put before the 'e' in the format argument of the `String.format(String format, Object... args)` method.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944822/format-double-value-in-scientific-Notation)

Comment: Add language tag please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem must be somewhere else, because your formatting is correct. 
I've tried this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    double number = 333333333333l*(double)333333333333l;
    System.out.println(String.format("%.5e",number));
}
```

And the result is `1.11111e+23`

...assuming it is Java. You can check here: https://ideone.com/VubwX7

Answer (score 0):

My problem was indeed not in the formatting of the String. There was a bit of code before the formatting that truncated the String at a certain length of characters if it was in decimal format already. What I did not realize was that the equation that I was using was already so large it actually NEEDED to be expressed in scientific notation. So when it was truncated, it deleted the "e+23", and left just a plain 'ol decimal number. It wasn't even reaching the code that formatted the String, ironically.