# Convert a number from scientific notation to decimal in JAVA

Tags: java, scientific-notation

I have a problem: a number is showing in scientific notation if it has 8 or more digits before the decimal point.
Is there a simple way to convert this number to decimal via a library or something?
I began creating a manual method to parse it out, but it seems overcomplicated.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
input example: 1.0225556677556E7
```

Edit: I also need to be able to identify a number that is in scientific notation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format double value in scientific notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944822/format-double-value-in-scientific-notation)

Comment: @JAL: That's the opposite.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes but the answers in there provide the relevant links to the documentation that will help the asker.

Comment: @JAL doesn't matter -- different question, different answer. SO is all about *not* having to read through all the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use NumberFormat your accomplish your goal easily.

```
String scientificNotation = "1.0225556677556E7";
Double scientificDouble = Double.parseDouble(scientificNotation);
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("################################################.###########################################");
decimalString = nf.format(scientificDouble);
```

To answer you're other question about matching scientific notation strings- you can use a regex and String.matches(). This one isn't perfect although the probability of getting false positives should be very low:

```
if(myString.matches("-?[\\d.]+(?:E-?\\d+)?")){
    //do work
}
```

Comment: @jeremy sorry not enough rep to upvote you but you deserve it! Thank you for the prompt responses