# Android Convert large Int into Scientific Notation

Tags: java, android, string.format

My app takes user input and show results based on:

```
String.format("%,.2", ave)
```

Such as:

```
2345.2302 -> 2,345.23
```

However, large results may be pushed out of the screen. I want to convert the number into scientific notation when the results exceed 9 digits (a maximum result of 9,999,999.99 before it is converted to scientific notation).

I am not sure how to use String.format to achieve this.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944822/format-double-value-in-scientific-notation help?

Comment: @mega12345mega thanks for the link but it is not what I'm looking for. I want the result to display normally and only change to scientific notation when the number of digits of the result exceeds 9.

Comment: You could simply test if it is too long. If so, convert it.